# Conditional formatting if certain conditions, but not others (COUNTIFS except)

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight column O if certain conditions are met. The formula below works great:

```
=COUNTIFS($O4, "<="&TODAY(), $N4, "<>NA")
```

However, I don't want it to work when $Q4 = `keep open`.

I couldn't find anything on the web about this.

Is there a way to have this work, only when $Q4 is not "keep open" and not highlight my cells when $Q4 = "keep open?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another criteria and range

```
=COUNTIFS($O4, "<="&TODAY(), $N4, "<>NA",$Q4,"<>keep open")
```

Comment: didn't realize it was so easy! lol unfortunately, this didn't work. when $Q4 is blank, it should highlight the cells in O. unfortunately, it doesn't. being blank is `"<>keep open"` so why is it not conditionally formatting? it does work when $Q4 is "keep open" (ie if $Q4="keep open" it does NOT highlight cells in col O)

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand your question? I used your modified formula, but it doesn’t work when $Q4 is blank. It doesn’t highlight the cell in col O when $Q is blank.

Comment: i figured it out! i was an idiot and for the last condition (not sure why) i entered `$Q4="<>keep open"` instead of using the comma. this is what it looked like: `=COUNTIFS($O4, "<="&TODAY(), $N4, "<>NA", $P4, "", $Q4="<>keep open")` your formula works; totally me not paying attention to detail. >.< thank you for your extensive help!! really appreciate it

Comment: I do have one other Q. I modified your formula a bit, but for some reason, cells in column O are being highlighted when they should not. See my test doc, sheet "COUNTIFS" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IWQWDK9piw_xFVm_48XZ8YAS_LQqXi6sd2GITLIfoAQ/edit#gid=1793641953

Comment: it is just a link to a shareable Google Doc - a test doc. I can post another Q. I've never heard about the Dawg Haus before! so cool! really appreciate the stack exchange/overflow community. you guys are awesome!